# Which of the given codes $p1,p2,p3,p4$ is the correct one for imposing assumption in ContourPlot3D using RegionFunction?

Tags: plotting, regions, assumptions, conditional, regionplot

I am using `ContourPlot3D` for the condition `f[x_, y_, z_] ==0` assuming that the assumption `x + 2 y > 0` holds. I apply the latter assumption by `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + 2 y > 0]`.

**My Questions.**

1. Which one of the four codes below i.e. `p1,p2,p3,p4` gives the result I am looking for (described above)? The only difference in them is the order/number of variables in `{...}` in `Function[{...}, x + 2 y > 0]`.
2. Why does the change in the order/number of variables in `{...}` in `Function[{...}, x + 2 y > 0]` yield a different result? I see that  `p1 & p3` give the same results.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = -x^3 - 4 x^2 y + 4 (-1 + z) x  y^2 + 8 y^3 (z + 1 y);

p1 = ContourPlot3D[ f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, -4, 4}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + 2 y > 0], PlotPoints -> 40];

p2 = ContourPlot3D[ f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, -4, 4}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, RegionFunction -> Function[{y, x}, x + 2 y > 0], PlotPoints -> 40];

p3 = ContourPlot3D[  f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, -4, 4}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + 2 y > 0], PlotPoints -> 40] ;
 
p4 = ContourPlot3D[  f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, -4, 4}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic,  RegionFunction -> Function[{y, z, x}, x + 2 y > 0], PlotPoints -> 40];

{  p1, p2, p3, p4}
```

the result

[image]

Comment: Both `Function[{y, x}, x + 2 y > 0]` and `Function[{y, z, x}, x + 2 y > 0]` are wrong since the order of the range is `{x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 6}`

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you very much for the comment. So, the rule is to have the same order as in the variable domains.  Then, I expect that if I change the order of the variables' ranges in `p2` to `{y, 0, 6}, {x, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}` the result should be the same as `p1` but if I am not mistaken, it is not.

Comment: We can use `ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, -4, 4}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, RegionFunction -> (1*#1 + 2*#2 + 0*#3 > 0 &),
  PlotPoints -> 40]`

Answer (score 0):

The names of local variables in a function definition are completely arbitrary. Only the position counts E.g.:

```
f1= Function[{x,y},x+y^2];
f2= Function[{y,x},x^2+y];
```

are equivalent:

```
f1[1, 2] == f2[1, 2]

True
```

However, the following are not equivalent:

```
f1 = Function[{x, y}, x  y^2];
f2 = Function[{y, x}, x  y^2];
f1[1, 2] == f2[1, 2]

False
```

Comment: Thanks. So, since my assumption `x + 2 y > 0` has two variables $x,y$, absence or presence of the third variable $z$ plays no role in `{...}` in `RegionFunction -> Function[{...}, x + 2 y > 0]`. I mean  `RegionFunction -> Function[{x,y}, x + 2 y > 0]` gives the same results as  `RegionFunction -> Function[{x,y,z}, x + 2 y > 0]`. am I correct?

Comment: This is correct inside "ContourPlot3D". But generally Function[{x,y},x y] is not equivalent to Function[{x,y,z}, x y]